# how to get the selected text from acropdf component to an edit directly with Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, pdf, axacropdf

I study preparing a dictionary programme with delphi. So far I have solved my problems about Word documents but I've got some problem about PDF documents.
I imported and installed the AcroPdf component with Delphi 7 and I want to get the word (or text) which was selected by dblclicking by user from pdf document which was viewed by the ACROPDF component in Delphi. If I can get it I'll send it the dictionary database directly. 
If you help me I'll be glad. Thank you...
Remzi MAKAK

Comment: Are you using the full version of Adobe Acrobat or the Reader?

Comment: Yes, I use Adob Acrobat X pro full version.

Comment: Dear friends don't you know anything about this subject?

Comment: Mr. MartynA is there any releationship with using full version of Adobe Acrobat?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "any relationship".  My answer does what I understand you to be asking, using Acrobat's automation library.  I'm afraid I don't know anything about axacropdf.

Comment: Mr.MartynA, thank you very much for your answer. I've got Acrobat X Pro full version and I use Delphi 7. I have imported AcroPdfLib_Tlb.Pas from Acrobat X and compiled it as AcroPdf component. But it doesn't let me onclick event and it doesn't me to get selected text.

Comment: I don;t have version X of Acrobat but I am wondering whether we are talking about the same Acrobat import unit.  Does your AcroPdfLib_Tlb.Pas contain declarations of interfaces such as CAcroApp and CAcroAVDoc?  If not, you need to import that unit using D7's Import facility.

Comment: "But it doesn't let me onclick event and it doesn't me to get selected text."  The OnClick event should be on your project's Main Form, not in Acrobat.  I've updated my answer to include a bit more detail of exactly what to do.

Comment: " AcroPdfLib_Tlb.Pas "  Btw, I think this may be the **wrong** file to import.   The name resembles the import unit which was generated from the Acrobat **Reader** program in older versions of Acrobat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following shows one way to get the selected text from a Pdf document which is
open in Adobe Acrobat Professional (v.8, English version).

**Update** The original version of this answer neglected to check the Boolean result of calling `MenuItemExecute` **and** specified the wrong argument to it.  Both these points are fixed in the updated version of this answer.  It turned out that the reason the call to `MenuItemExecute` was failing was that it is essential to call `BringToFront` on the Acrobat document before trying to copy the text selected in to to the clipboard.

1. Create a new Delphi VCL project.
2. In D7's IDE go to `Projects | Import Type Library`, and in the `Import Type Library` pop-up, scroll down until you see something like "Acrobat (Version 1.0) in the list of files, and 
   "TAcroApp, TAcroAVDoc..." in the `Class names` box.  That is the one you need to import.  Click the `Create unit` button/
3. In the project's main form file

   a.  Make sure it USES the Acrobat_Tlb.Pas unit from step 2.  You may need to add the path to wherever you saved Acrobat_Tlb.Pas to the SearchPath of your project.

   b.  Drop a TButton on the form, name it `btnGetSel`.  Drop a TEdit on the form and name it `edSelection`
4. Edit the source code of your main form unit as shown below.
5. <s>Set a debugger breakpoint on `Acrobat.MenuItemExecute('File->Copy');`</s>  Do **not** set a breakpoint within the `GetSelection` procedure as this is likely to defeat the call to `BringToFront` in it.
6. Close any running instance of Adobe Acrobat.  Check in Task Manager that there are no hidden instances of it running.  The reason for these step is to make sure that when you run your app, it "talks" to the instance of Acrobat that it starts, not another one.
7. Compile and run your app.  Once the app **and** Acrobat are open, switch to Acrobat, select some text, switch back to your app and click the `btnGetSel` button.

Code:

```
  uses ... Acrobat_Tlb, ClipBrd;

  TDefaultForm = class(TForm)
  [...]
  private
    FFileName: String;
    procedure GetSelection;
  public
    Acrobat : CAcroApp;
    PDDoc : CAcroPDDoc;
    AVDoc : CAcroAVDoc;
  end;

[...]

procedure TDefaultForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //  Adjust the following path to suit your system.  My application is
  //  in a folder on drive D:
  FFileName := ExtractfilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'Printed.Pdf';
  Acrobat := CoAcroApp.Create;
  Acrobat.Show;
  AVDoc := CoAcroAVDoc.Create;
  AVDoc.Open(FileName, FileName); // := Acrobat.GetAVDoc(0) as CAcroAVDoc; //

  PDDoc := AVDoc.GetPDDoc as CAcroPDDoc;
end;

procedure TDefaultForm.btnGetSelClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  GetSelection;
end;

procedure TDefaultForm.GetSelection;
begin
  // call this once some text is selected in Acrobat
  edSelection.Text := '';

  if AVDoc.BringToFront then  //  NB:  This call to BringToFront is essential for the call to MenuItemExecute('Copy') to succeed 
    Caption := 'BringToFront ok'
  else
    Caption := 'BringToFront failed';
  if Acrobat.MenuItemExecute('Copy') then
    Caption := 'Copy ok'
  else
    Caption := 'BringToFront failed';

  Sleep(100);  // Normally I would avoid ever calling Sleep in a Delphi     
  //  App's main thread.  In this case, it is to allow Acrobat time to transfer the selected
  //  text to the clipboard before we attempt to read it.

  try
    edSelection.Text := Clipboard.AsText;
  except
  end;

end;
```

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in "Acrobat_Tlb" when I first hand-edited it into the Uses list.  Fixed.

Comment: Mr.MartynA, thankyou very much for your help. I have got your answer, Now I'm trying to change it Acrobat XI, when I get result I am going to inform you.

Comment: Mr.MartynA, I tested the program codes with Acrobat XI pro full version but I couldn't get the success. I realized that ACROBAT.MENUITEMEXECUTE('FILE->COPY') doesn't work.

Comment: a)  Does the code in my answer compile for your?  b) Is your version of Acrobat in English or some other language?  c) If it is another language, have you tried using the translation of "File->Copy"?

Comment: Mr.MartynA; I have written the program and compiled succesfully. My Acrobat version is in Turkish and I have tried using the translation of "File->Copy" but it doesn't work successfully. Instead of using Acrobat.Menuitemexecute(..) If I use CTRL+C with the keyboard it gave me the selected text from clipboard but I need to get selected text with delphi code.

Comment: Please see update, which now correctly works for me with the English version of Acrobat.  I'm not sure if you need to translate "Copy" into Turkish to get it to work.  Please try both and let me know how you get on

Comment: Mr. MartynA, Thankyou very much for your help again. The last update is OK.

Comment: Mr. MartynA, after getting success with your update information I have tried   AVDoc.OpenInWindowEx(FFilename, Panel1.handle, 0, True, 0,0, 2, 0, 0, 0);  but it doesn't work successfully. I wonder It doesn't let us to use menuitemexecute() function.

Comment: I am glad you got it working.  Would you mind accepting my answer, please, as I think it answers the question you originally asked and took me an entire day to get it to work.  I think you had better ask about getting MenuItemExecute to work with AVDoc.OpenInWindowEX in a new question, because it is a separate problem.  Seeing as getting MenuItemExecute('Copy') requires a preceding call to BringToFront, I don't see how you could get that to work when the doc is being hosted in a non-Acrobat window.

Comment: Ok. Mr.Martyn. I accept your answer. But I don't know if there is anything to do in the form principles to accept the answer. If you help me I'll be glad. As you said I am going to ask a new question about last situation.

Comment: Sorry, when I said "accept", I meant in the SO sense.  In other words, you click the "tick" icon at the top left of the answer, and the SO s/ware marks the answer as accepted.

Comment: I followed all steps, but I get an error undeclared identifier "CAcroApp"

Comment: Sorry, but you obviously didn't follow all the steps correctly, otherwise you wouldn't get that error.